# Karma error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

while running Karma test running I am seeing all these weird errors. Any ideas?

[jenkins@xcclx0194 workspace]$ karma start karma.conf.js --single-run

INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://jenkins.test.com:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux)]: Connected on socket 287TYh_PCxnMv4F5SzII with id 8378863

PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) ERROR

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Toolbox.Base')

at /apps/devops/jenkins/home/jobs/UIMod-Jasmine-Karma/workspace/WebContent/js/controllers/common/base.controller.js:4
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux): Executed 4 of 38 ERROR (0.126 secs / 0.043 secs)

Thanks.

Comment: I will difficult to advise anything with the stack trace only...